# Caml query to fetch data from Sharepoint list for a specific Date

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I have a sharepoint list with one of hte columns being Created Date of Type DateTime and value allowed is OnlyDate.

The submitted date in my column is 05/18/2011. When I perform a search using the below CAML query, it does not give any results though I have two items with this date.

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Date_x0020_Created' /><Value Type='DateTime'>5/18/2011</Value></Eq></Where>
```

I dont understand what is wrong with this query. Someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint accepts datetime in ISO 8601 Datetime form in ***UTC***. The format is

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ
```

So for your example you can use

```
2011-05-18T00:00:00Z
```

[SPUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx) does provide a method to do this conversion.
For creating this in Java you can use the following method:

```
private String changeDateToISO8601(Date date) {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    String convertedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    return convertedDate;
}
```

---

P.S. You may not be able to find both the items using this just by `<Eq>` tag as there may be time difference. For this to work you need to enclose the dates in `<Leq>` and `<Geq>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your query using CAML query builder. To know about the basics of CAML query and how to use CAML query builder, read the following articles - they will help you out!

- [Basics of the CAML query](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/05/caml-query-tutorial-for-sharepoint.html)  and
- [Using CAML query builder](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-caml-query-builder-for-sharepoint.html)